# Why is rails 5 adding nextval method in schema file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

After upgrading to Rails 5 my schema file keeps getting altered when running db:migrate.  Rails is changing:

```
create_table "flightlessons", force: :cascade do |t|
```

to:

```
create_table "flightlessons", id: :integer, default: -> { "nextval('lessons_id_seq'::regclass)" }, force: :cascade do |t|
```

It only occurs on this one model.  Why is rails implementing nextval on this particular model?  And, why is it getting the model name wrong (lessons_id_seq should be flightlessons_id_seq).  Manually changing it to flightlessons_id_seq, however, results in the same no relation error.

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "lessons_id_seq" does not exist
```

To proceed, I simply alter the schema.rb file back to what that line 'should' be.  Then, I can migrate or test:prepare or whatever until the next time rails alters it back to using the nextval method.

Thank you for any insight into this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a bit long of an answer, so I've broken it into sections. Buckle up!

### My theory

My guess is that your development database *does* contain the `lessons_id_seq` sequence, and that its definition of `flightlessons.id` is set to depend on it (i.e., exactly what Rails is putting into your schema file).

How and why? You likely renamed the `lessons` table to `flightlessons` at some point in the past, but that rename didn't change the sequence that the table depended on -- and since `schema.rb` does **not** record sequences, the `lessons_id_seq` sequence does not get copied to your test database, and thus you get this error.

To verify my theory, run `rails db` and try the following commands:

```
\d lessons_id_seq
```

This should return the definition of that sequence. Then, try:

```
\d flightlessons
```

And look at the definition of the `id` column. I expect it to include `DEFAULT nextval('lessons_id_seq')`.

### Fixes

The easiest way to fix this is to switch to using `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb` (see [the docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps)). This will carry over the exact state of your database and avoid any interference or interpretation by Rails, which is what's causing your current issue. I always recommend `structure.sql` for production systems.

However, you can also go into your development database and change the sequence name:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE lessons_id_seq RENAME TO flightlessons_id_seq;
ALTER TABLE flightlessons ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('flightlessons_id_seq');
```

This would be a terrible idea on a production system, but if your issue is just local, it should rectify your current database state with your `schema.rb` and thus address your current problem. You may wish to encode that into a migration, if you want `rails db:drop db:create db:migrate` to work on a fresh app.

### Why now?

The behavior where Rails is dumping out the `default` value for your table's primary key may very well be new in Rails 5. Previously, Rails may have just trusted that your ID column had a sane default, and ignored whatever value it actually saw. But I haven't done the research to see if that's true or not.

Comment: This is the best answer I have ever gotten on StackOverflow!  Not only was I surprised to even get a response, but you were dead on correct---and beyond thorough in your explanation.  Thank you!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you again.  I am thoroughly impressed with your understanding of my question and your answer.  Fantastic!  Sometimes stackoverflow has the same affect on me as Facebook and I think "well, never going on there again".  But, its people like you who make this great.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Yours is the sort of bug that can drive a programmer insane, so I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: Extremely helpful question and answer. Just to add a little color, when rails creates a table in Postgresql, what seems to happen is it creates a sequence named "#{table_name}_id_seq". If the table uses a sequence other than that to generate ids, rails will put the sequence name in the schema.rb (as it did for @hellion, and for me). In my case I had manually dropped the table then re-created it, which resulted in a second sequence being created and being listed explicitly in the schema.rb.
Anyway... thank you!

Comment: Robert, let me just thank you. You deserve a Nubel Prize. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mentioned this "would be a terrible idea on a production system". How would you solve this in production?

Comment: @Marc my "terrible idea" warning only applies to running the commands directly on your prod database :) The "rename sequence and change the PK's default value" approach should work in production, too, but you'd need to be sure that the problem actually exists in production (Rails does not enforce that your dev schema actually matches your prod schema, so the symptom OP experienced could easily just be local to their machine). If you can confirm that, then a migration to rename the schema and updated the table to use the new schema should do the trick.

Comment: @RobertNubel Thanks for the explanation! I run into this problem whenever I clone the production database to my local machine. I tried fixing the `schema.rb`, but of course that kept getting overwritten anytime I would run a new migration. Will fix in production. Thank you!

Comment: Turns out it's a wonderful idea, not a terrible one, to rename the sequences in production :) If you don't do anything fancy with the sequences (like implementing your own Postgres functions that reference them by name), you can just do `ALTER SEQUENCE lessons_id_seq RENAME TO flightlessons_id_seq;` in production – the rename is instant and with no ill effects that we've seen. More details: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265569/how-can-i-safely-rename-a-sequence-in-postgresql-ideally-without-downtime

Answer (score 3):

The simplest fix is to just to rename the sequence in production to match the current table name. E.g. in a production Rails console:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ALTER SEQUENCE lessons_id_seq RENAME TO flightlessons_id_seq;")
```

Turns out it's fine to just rename it, if you haven't done anything fancy with the sequence (like implementing your own Postgres function that references it by name).

Apparently the table points to the sequence by ID, not by name, so the rename is instant and with no ill effects that we could see. More details here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265569/how-can-i-safely-rename-a-sequence-in-postgresql-ideally-without-downtime

We tried it on staging first, and verified that the ID sequence kept on ticking after making the change in staging and production. Everything just worked.

(Also see Robert Nubel's fantastic answer for more details on what's going on.)