# How to prevent rails from inserting `id: :integer` in schema.rb when creating a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Recently I started getting errors for certain models when creating new records:

> PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates
>   not-null constraint

This doesn't happen for all models, but only some of them and not always immediately. After some inspection I realized I get the error when 'id: :integer' appears in schema.rb file in the table creation line.

This is an example of a migration that creates a non-error table:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :main_title
      t.boolean :published
      t.string :short_title
      t.text :a_body
      t.string :a_image

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is what shows up in schema.rb:

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "main_title"
  t.boolean  "published"
  t.string   "short_title"
  t.text     "a_body"
  t.string   "a_image"
  t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
  t.string   "slug"
  t.string   "a_meta_title"
  t.string   "a_meta_description"
  t.string   "a_other"
  t.string   "a_comment"
  t.index ["slug"], name: "index_articles_on_slug", using: :btree
end
```

Now when the same was done with 'agents':

```
class CreateAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :agents do |t|
      t.boolean :status
      t.string :stripeId
      t.integer :UserID

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But resulting part of the schema.rb file looks differently:

```
create_table "agents", id: :integer, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean  "status"
  t.string   "stripeId"
  t.integer  "UserID"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

As you can see, for no reason that I can detect, the 'id: :integer' gets added. I tried to change it to :serial, dumping my database, reloading schema (advice found in all similar Stack Overflow questions) but nothing helped. In the past, I used to set up a new model but that is not a scalable solution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I also noticed that errors only happen locally but never in production (I use Heroku).

In case it's needed, models for comparison:

Article Model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :short_title, use: :slugged
end
```

Agent Model:

```
class Agent < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I use:

ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899)

Rails 5.0.6

psql (9.6.1, server 9.6.6)

**Update:**
To clarify what I'm looking for - I'd like to keep auto-generated ids, just prevent not-null violation error

Comment: Totally unrelated... but this case: `t.integer  "UserID"` is likely to confuse the hell out of rails (and possibly devs) at some point. rails assumes that a method that starts with a capital letter is a class-name, not a method/column name... rails standard would be to call this: `t.integer  "user_id"` instead :) or possibly even `t.references :user` (if you have a `User` class already). (Note: I understand if it's necessary for legacy reasons of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the argument `id: false` to your `create_table` call. Also, take note of the enclosing parentheses.

Check out the [API Dock reference](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table) when you get the chance.

```
class CreateAgents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table(:agents, id: false) do |t|
      t.boolean :status
      t.string :stripeId
      t.integer :UserID

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is a nit-picky addition, but you probably want to enforce some consistency in your naming conventions. Either use "Id" or "ID" in your column names, but don't mix and match. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks, @MarsAtomic I'm reading the link you provided, that sounds like a reasonable solution but ideally, I'd like to keep auto-generated ids (that happened to me with other models too that's why I'd love to find a universal solution for not having to deal with this issue - ideally). Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: @Socha Could not reproduce. My schema comes up clean using PG and Rails 5.1. Maybe related to friendly_id?

Comment: It must have been some local db problem, I followed steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38666275/8335053 altering sequence in local postgres db table and I'm not getting the error. I'm going to accept your answer @MarsAtomic because it is a good solution and might help others too.