# Rails test error. PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR: cannot drop table addr because extension postgis_tiger_geocoder requires it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, rspec-rails, minitest

Trying to run tests in Rails

`PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table addr because extension postgis_tiger_geocoder requires it
HINT:  You can drop extension postgis_tiger_geocoder instead.`

Same error whether RSpec or minitest. I probably screwed up something migrating to Rails 6.

The error points to db/schema.rb:21 which is

`create_table "addr", primary_key: "gid", id: :integer, default: -> { "nextval('addr_gid_seq'::regclass)" }, force: :cascade do |t|`

which presumably is something to do with postgis_tiger_geocoder which I do want to keep. The table addr is in the tiger data schema that I assume is installed with postgis_tiger_geocoder. But no idea what is trying to drop it. Does addr have to be dropped before creating it again?

Running the test for [2.8.1. Tiger Geocoder Enabling your PostGIS database: Using Extension](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#install_tiger_geocoder_extension) Item 3 confirms my installation is correct.

How do I get out of this?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of things but I think it was adding a line to config/application.rb
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql

per https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps which I found via [Why is rails 5 adding nextval method in schema file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665959/why-is-rails-5-adding-nextval-method-in-schema-file) which addressed a related problem.